# Value of resistance R from the equation: \$ R = \frac{t}{C\, \ln\frac{U_0}{U}} \$ for specific value of \$U_0\$ = 300 V at time t =0

Tags: resistance

I have a question regarding the value or resistance \$R\$ at time t = 0 s, when original voltage is \$U_0 = 300\text{ V}\$ and the capacity \$C = 47\text{ nF}\$ - if the wanted resistance can be described as:

$$
 R = \frac{t}{C\, \ln\frac{U_0}{U}}.
$$
I do have table of values:

[image]

but honestly I do not really believe my calculations. To me, to get the value of resistance as teraohms seems strange.
My calculation for time t = 10 min:
$$
R =  \frac{10 \cdot 60}{(47 \cdot 10^{-9})\, \ln\Big(\frac{300}{299}\Big)} =  3,823 \cdot 10^{12} \text{ }\Omega
$$
But for value at time t = 0 s:
$$
R =  \frac{0 \cdot 60}{(47 \cdot 10^{-9})\, \ln\Big(\frac{300}{300}\Big)} =  \frac{0}{(47 \cdot 10^{-9})\, \cdot 0} =  0 \text{ }\Omega
$$
Thank you for any suggestions/ideas.... if my calculations are right or where I went wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the equation is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a RC element, then for charging phase:

$$U=U_0(1-e^\frac{-t}{RC})$$

$$R= -\dfrac{t}{C \cdot ln(1-\dfrac{U}{U_0})}$$

For discharging phase:

$$U=U_0 \cdot e^\frac{-t}{RC}$$

$$R= -\dfrac{t}{C \cdot ln\dfrac{U}{U_0}} = \dfrac{t}{C \cdot ln\dfrac{U_0}{U}}$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhjoCF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At the time t=0 it can be solvable, since the discharging didn't take place yet. You have no valid measurement on base you could solve something. However the R could be anything except 0.

EDIT:

I think it's better to calculate the R for each time difference and only then use the mean value of R:

$$U_{n+1}=U_n \cdot e^\frac{-(t_{n+1} - t_n)}{RC}$$

$$R_n=\dfrac{(t_{n+1} - t_n)}{C \cdot ln\dfrac{U_n}{U_{n+1}}}$$

Comment: Great, thank you a lot! If I could ask - in your opinion - if i find an average value of R from following values of U(t) , is it possible to consider that R at t=0 equal to found average of R?

Comment: @ElisLovelace Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about the resistance of a capacitor, or R = V/I, then these numbers do make sense. At t=0 where the capacitor has not charged yet, the capacitor pull in as much current as it can handle, such that R as defined as R=V/I will be ~0 Ω (ignoring any series resistance).

After the capacitor charges up, the current will slow to a stop exponentially, such that R approaches infinity as t -> infinity.

It takes milliseconds to charge a cap that size with no series resistance, so plugging in large numbers for t will give you arbitrarily large resistance.